# How to add images in a radbutton in winforms?

Tags: .net, winforms, rad-controls

I am currently using vb.net in Visual Studio 2010 and am using radbuttons for winforms.

How can I have a button which has an image on the left part and a text on the right?
I can't find the right property to set the image.

Yes, i can set the property of Displaystyle (image and text) and the imagealignment (middleleft)

anyone who can share his knowledge?

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Set `Appearance` to `Appearance.Button`

Set the `Image` property

Set `TextImageRelation` to `TextImageRelation.ImageBeforeText`

The default appearance `Appearance.Norm` shows the traditional radio button with the image  in the label part.

Answer (score 1):

**If your question is a about a normal button** then you can change the image property of the button from the  properties window in Visual Studio.

If you are generation the button dynamically you can:

```
yourbuttonobject.Image = Image.FromFile(@"path to your image");
this.Controls.Add(yourbuttonobject);//controls have to be added to a container control
```

**If your question is about the telerik radbutton control** from Telerik
[Telerik Rad Buttons for WinForms](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0c343c66-bc2f-46fb-bbee-9aa17d535283)
then you can theme the button like this [How to theme the Telerik radbutton button](http://www.telerik.com/help/winforms/buttons-button-html-like-text-formatting.html)

**If your question is about a radiobutton** you theme it from the properties window or through code like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            RadioButton dynamicRadioButton = new RadioButton();
            dynamicRadioButton.Text = "I am a Dynamic RadioButton";
            dynamicRadioButton.Location = new Point(20, 20);
            dynamicRadioButton.Height = 40;
            dynamicRadioButton.Width = 300;
            dynamicRadioButton.Name = "DynamicRadioButton";
            dynamicRadioButton.Image = Image.FromFile(@"your_image_path");
            this.Controls.Add(dynamicRadioButton);
        }
```